# Programming against a PLC via OPC protocol with C#

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop, plc, opc

I'm running this code to connect to a plc.

```
   System.Guid guid=new Guid("75d00bbb-dda5-11d1-b944-9e614d000000"); 
   System.Type t=Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid,node,true); 
   object COMobject=System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
   opcServer = (IOPCServer) COMobject;
```

using the opc protocol as previously mentioned. I have little to no experience with this, so little that I cant even identify if this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {75D00BBB-DDA5-11D1-B944-9E614D000000} from machine 192.168.100.10 failed due to the following error: 800706ba 192.168.100.10.

is caused by interop or the plc...

Comment: According Dr. Google this is "RPC server not available".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was the wrong guid.. the right guid for a Phoenix Contact AX OPC-Server is

> {aa6c2a7c-f097-4be3-9153-f44ce2a3d916}

if anyone else needs it.